# Using cURL and multi threading in C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, httprequest

I have a POST request which I want to repeat it without any time shift. I have done it with `requests` in `python`.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'SOME URL'
headers = {"headers"}
payload ={"some payload here"}
data = json.dumps(payload)
session = requests.Session()

def SendOrder():
    r = session.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)
    print(r.text)

for i in range(2000):
    Thread(target=SendOrder,args=[]).start()
```

And it perfectly works and each thread end it self after sending post request. I implemented in C++ with `cURL` :

```
int Requst(CURL *curl) {

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    double tt = 0.000;
    int curlRC = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &tt);
    printf("%.8lf\n", tt);
    return 0;

}
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36");
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        std::string jsonstr = "PAYLOAD";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 2L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsonstr.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            std::thread(Requst, curl);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
```

I want to thread end itself after making `Request` call. I don't know C++ well.
Or anyway to make something like python code?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::thread` is just a wrapper class around the native (actual) thread. You should keep the `std::thread` instance around and `join()` with it before it's destroyed, otherwise `std::thread`'s destructor will abort the program.

You should also invoke `curl_easy_*` inside the thread.

Something like this

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
   threads.emplace_back([&]{ // creates and starts a thread
       CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
       curl_easy_setopt(...
       . . .
       curl_easy_perform();
       curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   });
}
for (auto& t : threads) { // wait for all threads to finish
    t.join();
}
```

Having said that, for good performance it's better to use the [curl multi API](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html). It uses async sockets instead of threads.

Here are some examples how to use the curl multi API: [multi-poll.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-poll.html) and [10-at-a-time.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/10-at-a-time.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. `Curl Multi API` send requests at same time. But I want to send them each after each other without any time shift. Your code do it perfectly. Is it possible to define only one `curl` handler instance and use it to send requests?
I mean, `CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();` defined only one time and use `curl_easy_perform();` for creating threads?

Comment: With threads the requests will also be sent at the same time. To send and receive requests one after another you simply need a `for`-loop. A single `CURL*` is a single request, it cannot perform multiple times.

Comment: How can I send requests one after another without waiting for response? Each request take 30 millisecond, I just want to send them without this 30 millisecond lag.

Comment: @rustyx Your code is missing the curl_global_init(); function

Comment: Also this is maybe a better example of using threading using the multi API: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html